# tcsh history contains junk or special charecters

Tags: csh, tcsh, solaris-10

In tcsh shell. When we do ctrl+c junk charecters getting printed in history. Contents of /etc/.cshrc are below

```
# vi /etc/.cshrc
set TERMINAL=`who am i | nawk '{print $NF}' | tr -d '()'`
set history= (1000 "%h $TERMINAL %D/%W/%Y %T %R\n")
set histfile=($HOME/.History_Save/.history_$TERMINAL)
set savehist= (1000 merge)
alias precmd 'history -M; history -S'

# ctrl+c
# history
    18  15:04   ^[[K#+1608283370
    19  15:04   history
```

Is it possible to avoid printing junk charecters( ^[[K#+1608283370 ) or is it the behaviour of tcsh shell?

OS: Solaris10

TIA

Comment: Which version are you using? I don't see this with tcsh 6.22.03, but it could be related to the terminal. I see a number of entries regarding to history in the [Fixes](https://github.com/tcsh-org/tcsh/blob/master/Fixes) file in the last year or so.

Comment: Verison is: tcsh 6.19.00 (Astron) 2015-05-21 (i386-sun-solaris) options wide,nls,dl,al,kan,sm,rh,color,filec

Comment: So that's more than five years old; I'd try updating to a newer version to start with. I remember there were a bunch of fixed for these kind of issues a few years ago as well. If you can't update, then I guess you're stuck with this as it's probably just a bug in tcsh.